# Deserializing JSON from API call Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

An API call that I use returns a JSON similar to below

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "Id": "Test01",
                "Version": ""

            }
        ],
        "count": 0
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can Deserialize this Dynamically or Should I create POCO classes to do so ?

Comment: The answer is yes, and probably yes. In the first part you can use `JObject.Parse`, in the second part, why not just build a concrete class and be strongly typed

Comment: Hi @MichaelRandall Isnt it better off to do so dynmically over creating POCO classes ?

Comment: C# is  a strongly typed language, its convention to use strongly typed methodologies. However, the json that comes back from a web call is sometimes bewildering to say the least and random at worst. there are cases where you will have to explore the json results using something like JObject.

Comment: Do yo think this is an instance where JObject is more suitable ? Why Im asking this is , I think it would be ridiculos to have a class name 'D' but then again this the way that the  nuget API returns the JSON'

Comment: If your results consists of object that will **always** have `Id` and `version`, then use POCO. If not and you expect version in one object and totally different properties in the next, go with dynamic object instead of strong typed classes

Comment: @Devss you can use attributes to have more helpful class names.  Like MichaelRandall said.  If you know the json will not change, use the benefits of a strongly typed language.

Comment: To @Jawad's point, your POCO class doesn't have to define everything, just the properties you know for sure will be there and you care about retrieving.  However, if there is a possibility that those properties won't exist in a response and you need to conditionally check for that, then stick with JObject

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments , I will give a common reply here :- inside the results array there is a bunch of other information aswell but I require here is only the ID and version , hence I think as you guys suggested going forward with POCO would make more sense right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question, I am using the `Newtonsoft` JSON library which is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET.

You can go both ways here to de-serialize your `JSON` string:

1) Using POCO classes for your `JSON` string:

```
public class Result
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public D d { get; set; }
}
```

To de-serialize:

```
var Sresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

OR

2) You can use `dynamic` if you do not want to use the `POCO` classes:

```
var dynamicresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

Output:

```
Id: Test01
Version: 
Count: 0
```

A working example illustrating both the cases can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1zqGWf):